# How to solve- Connection to 192.168.X.X closed?

Tags: python, ssh

My code looks like this:

```
def op():
    cmd = "ssh -t user@ip top -bn 1 >data.txt"
    os.system(cmd)
    #does some other operations and then returns some variables, say a,b,c
    return (a,b,c)


k=1
while k<5:
    print(op())
    k+=1
```

The first time the `while` loop runs (at k=1), I get the variable values as expected. However, in every subsequent iteration, I get the following error message:

```
Connection to 192.168.xxx.xxx closed.
```

All my variables are empty as well. How can this be fixed?

I assume this has something to do with 'closing' the SSH connection and then re-starting it at the beginning of every iteration, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: you can't get values from `os.system()`. You will have to use module  `subprocess` - ie `suprocess.run` and then you can get text from `stdout`.

Comment: you may want to have a look at this: https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may not be a direct solution to your problem. However, it's always advisable to use python ssh interfaces instead of direct execution of shell commands.

Paramiko is one such python sshv2 implementation.

Current documentation : http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/

Example code:
[SSH examples](https://www.adampalmer.me/iodigitalsec/2014/11/23/ssh-sftp-paramiko-python/)

```
    import paramiko 
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    try:
        ssh.connect('localhost', username=username, password=password)
    except paramiko.SSHException:
        print "Connection Failed"
        quit()
```

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("top -bn")

for line in stdout.readlines():
        print line.strip()
ssh.close()
```